# How to get this code to work by calling event on Div instead of button?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a little web app todo list. I am trying to run an eventListener on my customizeDiv but for some reason the code won't work.

Description of program:

This todo list will allow the user to add tasks to a list, but the code provided has to do with customization of the list. The user can click 'customize list' which will then create another button called 'List Color' (the only option right now). Once clicked an input field will appear allowing the user to enter a color, changing the background color of the body element.

Right now I have nested event listeners but I heard this is not good practice. This program currently works using nested event listeners. I am trying to avoid that and also am trying to find out why I can't get it to work when using an event listener on the customizeDiv instead of the customizeButton initially. Here are all declared variables being used:

```
//Div containing all customization buttons
const customizeDiv = document.getElementById('customization');
/*This button allows the user to select what part of the list they want
  to customize, right now it only contains one button 'List Color'. When
  clicked, the user will enter a color into an input text field, changing
  the background-color of the body.*/
const customizeButton = document.createElement('button');   
customizeButton.textContent = 'Customize your list';
customizeDiv.appendChild(customizeButton);

  //Event listener on the customization button
  customizeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const colorButton = createButtonOnMenu('button', 'textContent', 'List Color');
    customizeDiv.removeChild(customizeDiv.firstChild);
    customizeDiv.appendChild(colorButton);

    //Event listener when user selects to change list color
    colorButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

      //Create the necessary elements to create new text submit.
      const colorForm = document.createElement('form');
      const colorInput = document.createElement('input');
      const colorChangeButton = document.createElement('button');

      colorChangeButton.type = 'submit';
      colorChangeButton.textContent = 'Submit Color';
      colorChangeButton.id = 'setColor';
      colorInput.type = 'text';
      colorInput.placeholder = 'Enter Color';
      colorInput.id = "colorInput";
      colorForm.id = "colorForm";

      colorForm.appendChild(colorInput);
      customizeDiv.appendChild(colorForm);
      customizeDiv.removeChild(colorButton);

      customizeDiv.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const body = document.getElementById('myBody');

        if(colorInput.value === ''){
          alert('Please enter a valid color!');
        }else {
          body.style.backgroundColor = colorInput.value;

          if(colorForm.parentNode){
            customizeDiv.removeChild(colorForm);
            customizeDiv.appendChild(customizeButton);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: *"Right now I have nested event listeners but I heard this is not good practice."* - But do you know *why* it is not a good practice? It's not a matter of preference, it's that it almost never makes sense (because you end up with duplicate event handlers on the same elements).

Comment: No, I believe it might not be necessary but the way I've coded this, it's the only way my todo list works. I'm trying to find out if my program can work without nesting the event listeners. Perhaps using event targeting and if statements on the buttons but some of my buttons only appear once a certain event is satisfied.

Comment: Solved the issue by creating an event listener on the div and then using if statements to determine which button was being click in order to create new elements necessary for the program to work how I wished.